# Token-specific claims for 2FA

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, two-factor-authentication, totp

I am looking to implement my own custom 2FA ([TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm)-based, e.g. usable by Google Authenticator and similar apps) for Firebase Authentication (using email/password authentication). Verifying the code is simple. Implement TOTP or use a library in a cloud function and test that against a code sent from the client. However, remembering that a session is valid (has been 2FA-authed) is a different story. I could try custom claims, but those apply to all new sessions, not just the current one.

What I would like to do is somehow issue a new ID token from a cloud function with a custom claim (e.g. `trusted: true`) that *only exists on that token* and no future ones.